# Simple Validate Five Digit Zipcode using Regex

Tags: ruby

I am writing a program that allows a user to enter a five-digit zip code to get a listing of local movie theaters and their listings. I am scraping the information later on in the program to populate theater and movie objects. Eventually, I will figure out a way to persist all of that data. But at this point in my CLI file, I am wanting the user to enter either a five-digit zip code or the word exit. Here is the code so far...

```
def program_input
  input = gets
  if input.chomp == "exit"
    puts "Enjoy your movie!"
  elsif input.chomp == #five digit zipcode validator
    sleep(0.5)
    print "Calculating"
    sleep(0.25)
    print "."
    sleep(0.25)
    print "."
    sleep(0.25)
    print "."
    zip_code = input.chomp
    scraper = Scraper.new(zip_code)
  end
end
```

What I need is on the `elsif` statement line. I want to use `regex` or something to validate that the input is a five-digit number like a zip code. I do not want to use an external gem, and I don't want to validate against a list of all five-digit zip codes.

I thought about validating the number to be in a range of 00001 to 99999. Or look at a list of zipcodes and find the one that has the lowest number and the zip code that numerically is higher and to accept all numbers in that range, but I realize that there would be a ton of gaps of numbers that fit that logic, without actually being a valid zip code.

Essentially I want the program to exit if the user types exit. I am going to be adding the downcase statement there to decapitalize any letters before checking if it is lowercase "exit". But if the user types in a valid five-digit zip code, I would like it to continue with the program....As in inject that zipcode into a URL, and then scraping that URL for the information the program needs before building theater and movie objects and returning that information to the user. I didn't show that part of the code because it is already written and working when a 5 digit zip is passed on the `scraper` line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use a `case statement` here because it uses the methods `===` for determining matches.

```
response = gets.chomp

case response
when "exit"
  puts "Enjoy your movie!"
when /\A\d{5}\z/
  # process zip code given by response
else
  # ?
end
```

Note `/\A\d{5}\z/ === "01234" #=> true`. See [Regexp#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). The regular expression reads, "match the beginning of the string (`\A`), followed by five digits (`\d{5}`), followed by the end of the string (`\z`).

`when "exit"` could be replaced by, for example, `/\A[Ee]xit\z/` if it is desired that the response `"Exit"` should have the same effect as `"exit"`.